# Retrieving data from specific columns of multiple rows in sql

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table which stores information as follows and has ID as the primary key:

Link for the table view: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4UzXmbWLTJZaU84WnVZMUJDT3M/view?usp=sharing

```
ID  ScheduleDate    WorkArea    Employee1   Hours1  Employee2   Hours2  Employee3   Hours3  Employee4   Hours4  Employee5   Hours5  Employee6   Hours6  Employee7   Hours7  Employee8   Hours8
1   7/1/2014    W1  A   8   B   7   C   4   D   3   NULL    0   NULL    0   NULL    0   NULL    0
2   7/1/2014    W2  B   8   C   8               0       0       0       0       NULL
3   7/1/2014    W3  C   8   A   8   E   8   F   8   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   7/1/2014    W4  D   8   B   8   F   8                   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   7/1/2014    W5  E   8   C   8       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
6   7/1/2014    W6  F   8   D   8       8       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
7   8/1/2014    W1  G   4       NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   8/1/2014    W2  A   4       NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9   8/1/2014    W3  B   8   F   8       8       8   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

For any particular `ScheduleDate`, there can be only one `WorkArea` (combination of `ScheduleDate` and `WorkArea` is unique). Now, I want to check if the sum of hours of the particular employee is greater than 8 hours or not in any single date. For example, the sum of hours of employee A for the particular date (can be hour1, hour2 or anything based on employee's placement in the table) should not be more than 8 hours. How do I check that?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Look into `unpivot`.

Comment: @shawnt00 Can you please tell me how? There are around 42 unique employees and 18 unique work area.

Comment: I think your problem is going to be that you need to unpivot the columns in pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really strictly need the aliases on each of the union-ed queries:

```
with t as (
    select ScheduleDate, Workarea, Employee1 as Employee, Hours1 as Hrs union all
    select ScheduleDate, Workarea, Employee2 as Employee, Hours2 as Hrs union all
    ...
    select ScheduleDate, Employee8 as Employee, Hours8 as Hrs
)
select ScheduleDate, Employee, sum(Hrs) as [Hours]
from t
group by ScheduleDate, Employee
having sum(Hrs) > 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. this query gives me the list of ScheduleDate, Workarea having total hours more than 8 hours. But I need to know the employees who has worked more than 8 hours on a single day regardless of the workarea.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. I replaced the work area with employee and this gives me my solution. So, final query is
';with t as (
    select ScheduleDate, Workarea, Employee1 as Employee, Hours1 as Hrs from workschedule_ union all
    select ScheduleDate, Workarea, Employee2 as Employee, Hours2 as Hrs from workschedule_ union all
   
    select ScheduleDate, Workarea, Employee8 as Employee, Hours8 as Hrs from workschedule_ 
) select Employee,ScheduleDate,  sum(Hrs) as [Hours]
 from t
 group by Employee,ScheduleDate
 having sum(Hrs) > 8'
Thanks a lot @shawnt00. I am not able to accept that as an answer

Comment: I wasn't totally sure how the workarea fit into your final results and I was rushing out the door. If you want to be able to query this across multiple dates you'll want to leave in the ScheduleDate grouping though.